# what's lq & uq in microbenchmark library?

Tags: r, microbenchmark

Sorry for asking newbie question. I don't how to interpret the lq and uq column in the result of microbenchmark. Here is an example:

```
Unit: microseconds
       expr      min       lq   median       uq         max neval
f(1000, 1) 1082.875 1139.485 1151.071 1162.327 1199918.296  1000
g(1000, 1)  193.004  219.157  221.806  228.427    1099.097  1000
```

Comment: Just fyi, With this function, you generally want to concentrate on the median values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lower and upper quartiles, ie 25% and 75% of the distribution with median being 50%.

Comment: What should be expected, thanks for confirming it's exactly 25%-ile and 75%-ile.